# Expected number of different digits of random $5$-digit number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

> A random $5$-digit number is chosen. What is the expected number of different digits? (For this question, numbers with leading zeros like $00585$ are considered $5$-digit
> numbers.)

We want to calculate:$${{{5(10)(9)(8)(7)(6)} + 4\binom{5}{2}(10)(9)(8)(7) + 3\binom{5}{3}(10)(9)(8) + 2\binom{5}{4}(10)(9) + 10}\over{10^5}}$$I ended up getting ${{37531}\over{10000}} = 3.7531$. Is this correct? If not, then what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a few cases. Take for example, when you have $3$ different digits form the number. It can be $2$ of the digits appear twice each and third digit once OR one of the digits appear thrice and other two digits appear once each. Otherwise it seems fine.

Here is how I am doing it. I am choosing different digits first, then I am choosing repeating digit(s) and finally I am permuting them. So expected number of different digits is,

$ \displaystyle \left[5 \cdot \binom{10}{5} \cdot 5! + 4 \cdot \binom{10}{4} \cdot 4 \cdot \frac{5!}{2!} + 3 \cdot \binom{10}{3} \cdot 3 \cdot \left(\frac{5!}{3!} + \frac{5!}{2! \ 2!} \right) + 2 \cdot \binom{10}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot \left(\frac{5!}{4!} + \frac{5!}{3! \ 2!} \right) + 10 \right] / 10^5 = \frac{40951}{10000}$

Edit: Alternatively, we can apply Stirling Number of the second kind or Principle of Inclusion Exclusion. Here is using Stirling Number of the second kind,

$ \displaystyle \sum \limits_{i = 1}^5 i \cdot \binom{10}{i} \cdot StirlingS2[5,i] \cdot i! = 409510$

where $i$ is the number of digits, ${10 \choose i}$ is the number of ways to choose them and  $i! \cdot StirlingS2[5,i]$ is the number of ways for chosen digits to make $5$ digit number with each of the chosen digits appearing at least once.

Comment: I wrote a program to brute-force this, and I can comfirm that $40951/10000$ is the correct answer.

Comment: @TonyK thanks for checking

Answer (score 6):

Just use linearity.  Assign an indicator function to each digit (according to whether or not it appears).

Given that $0$ is allowed to come first, the probability that any specified digit appears is $1-\left(\frac 9{10}\right)^5$

Thus the answer is $$10\times \left(1-\left(\frac 9{10}\right)^5\right)=\frac {10^5-9^5}{10^4}=\frac {40951}{10000}$$

Comment: A third method would be that the probability/expectation that the $n$-th digit is new( appears for the first time) is $\left({9}\middle/{10}\right)^{n-1}$, so the expected count for distinct digits is $\sum_{n=1}^5 (9/10)^{n-1}$ .